# mark a specific word after each space

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I'm trying to warning the user if he types a word that is not necessary in a textarea.

its just a little validation for some words.

i reach making something like this:

```
var words = "hello";
$("textarea").keyup(function(e){
    var spliting = $("textarea").val().split(" ");
    if(e.keyCode == 32){ // when the user hits space bar
        if($.inArray(words, spliting) != -1){
            $("span").css("background","red");
        }else{
            $("span").css("background","green");
        }
    }
});​
```

is this the best way of doing this ?

and how can i migrate the variable `words` as a `array`, if i need to check more then one word?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f5TDk/25/)

Comment: yes, this is good way to make it

Comment: 1. Your handler doesn't fire for paste / drag and drop text events; 2. What if someone erases a space? That automatically generates a new set of words; `keyup` is very weak to detect user input IMO. Use a combination of [`input`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljhxklln.php)/[`propertychange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536956(v=vs.85).aspx) or intervals for a sturdy validation.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté yes, didi'nt post here as a final option/code. Thanks for the typs;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use an array, you will need to loop over each word in it and loop over each word in the split array. However, you can return on the first match:

```
var words = ["hello","goodbye"];
$("textarea").keyup(function(e){

        var spliting = $("textarea").val().split(" ");

        for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
          if($.inArray(words[i], spliting) != -1){
              $("span").css("background","red");
              // break on first match since there is no need to continue looping
              // if it is already red.
              break;
          }else{
              $("span").css("background","green");
          }
        }
});​
```

I have removed the check for spaces. Even though it makes the function more efficient, you need to be wary of cases when someone goes back to correct spelling and ends up with an invalid word. The way you had it, those cases would never cause the flagged words to be found unless a space was typed later.

It would be advisable to call this function for `onchange` and `blur` events as well, since typing is not the only way users enter input into form inputs.

[Here is the updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f5TDk/28/)

Comment: hahaha wow! +1 you beat me to it :( look at my jsFiddle, I even called them hello and goodbye too lol http://jsfiddle.net/ZxcG4/

Comment: Thanks michael, this is a small validation (reminder), nothing rude. You provide much more then i need, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `.split` the input every time a key is pressed, this is a situation where a regular expression is to be preferred:

**[Check the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5TDk/26/)**

To generate the expression based on an array:

```
var blackList = ['hello','world'];
var expression = new RegExp('\\b(' + blackList.join('|') + ')\\b','i');

$("textarea").keyup(function(e)
{
  //if (e.keyCode === 32)
  //{in comment after reading the answer posted by Michael Berkowski
        if ($(this).val().match(expression))
        {
            $("span").css("background","red");
            return;
        }
        $("span").css("background","green");
  //}
});​
```